# Automatically store value upon session creation using express-session and passportjs

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, express-session

I am trying to save add a token to my session object just before creation. I am able to do this as follows as tokens are created when `req.logIn` is called:

```
    req.logIn(user, (err) => {
        if (err) return res.error(401);
        req.session.extraToken = generateExtraToken();
        return res.success({ redirectPath: "/", uid: user.id });
    });
```

This works, the `extraToken` is stored. But I use `req.logIn` a few more times in the codebase. In the future, more of these calls might be added. So I am looking for a way to automatically add this `extraToken` field without needing to explicitly add it every time I use `req.logIn`.

Is this possible? It should only happen on the generation of a new session, not when an existing one is updated.

As a current workaround, I do the following to improve DX:

```
function handleLoginAndCreateSessionCreation(req: Request, res: Response, user: Creds, opt?: { redirectPath?: string }) {
    req.logIn(user, (err) => {
        if (err) return res.error(401);
        req.session.extraToken = generateExtraToken();
        return res.success({ redirectPath: opt?.redirectPath || "/", uid: user.id });
    });
}
```

Which helps, but is still not quite what I'm after as developers might forget to use this.

My session middleware is setup as follows:

```
    const sessionParser = session({
        secret: "my secret",
        resave: false,
        cookie: { httpOnly: true, secure: true, sameSite: "strict" },
        saveUninitialized: false,
        proxy: true,
        store: createSessionStoreConnection(dbClient),
    });
```

I am using [connect-mongo](https://github.com/jdesboeufs/connect-mongo#readme) for the store. I would really prefer not having to write my own store implementation as `connect-mongo` has been thoroughly tested.